# PL/SQL: While Loop not waiting for inner procedures to complete

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to run 4 different procedures in one 'main' procedure using a *while loop*. I need this *while loop* to run for '5 minutes' (Condition).

My main procedure code:

```
PROCEDURE P_TEMP_MAIN IS
    -- Declare Variables
    l_start           NUMBER;
    v_loop_window     DATE;
    v_purge_year      NUMBER(4);
    v_increment_limit NUMBER(10):= 100000; -- LIMIT INCREMENT to be set
    v_counter         NUMBER:= 0;   
  BEGIN
    l_start      := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
    v_purge_year := F_TEMP_GET_YEAR();

    SELECT sysdate + interval '5' minute INTO v_loop_window from dual; -- Set the TIME INTERVAL for the purging activity

    WHILE (SYSDATE <= v_loop_window) LOOP

      P_TEMP_CHECK_MIN(v_purge_year);
      -- TO-DO: Check year before purging.    
      P_TEMP_PURGE(F_TEMP_GET_MIN(v_purge_year),F_TEMP_GET_MAX(v_purge_year,v_increment_limit),v_increment_limit);
      P_TEMP_UPDATE_MIN(v_purge_year,v_increment_limit);

      v_counter := v_counter + 1;   
    END LOOP;

    -- TO-DO: Include Output Logs. (Ex: Mails and output data like Rows updated and time taken)
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('LOOP count = ' ||
                         (v_counter));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Time taken = ' ||
                         (DBMS_UTILITY.get_time - l_start));

  END P_TEMP_MAIN;
```

Output:

```
SQL> execute P_TEMP_MAIN;
LOOP count = 804361
Time taken = 30049 
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

**NOTE** : Procedure `P_TEMP_PURGE` takes **2 mins** to run everytime.

**Question** : Why is the ***WHILE LOOP*** Looping without waiting for the inner procedures to complete?

Comment: Can you please execute the procedure `P_TEMP_PURGE` alone, with same parameters as passed in your code and recheck the time to execute it with given parameters?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the NOTE, I have executed the procedure `P_TEMP_PURGE`  alone before, but, without the parameters. During the testing of this procedure  `P_TEMP_PURGE`, I had hard coded the data in the procedure itself.

Comment: It is waiting.  There is no conditional code in the loop, so must be a different issue.

Comment: `v_loop_window := sysdate + interval '5' minute;` is shorter than `select ... into ... from dual;`

Comment: Can you simply check your code with only following change: while loop condition `WHILE ( V_COUNTER = 0)` and provide the output?

Comment: This seems like something that would be cleared up with a quick debug session. Loops don't skip procedure calls.

Comment: Most likely the output of `F_TEMP_GET_YEAR()` or the behaviour of your other procedures is not what you expect. It's impossible to say why this is without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to a misinterpretation of how DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME functions. If we look at the description from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_util.htm#i1002765):

"This function determines the current time in 100th's of a second. This subprogram is primarily used for determining elapsed time. The subprogram is called twice – at the beginning and end of some process – and then the first (earlier) number is subtracted from the second (later) number to determine the time elapsed."

So on your results, Time taken = 30049 is in hundredths of seconds.  You need to convert it to minutes:

```
            30049/100/60 = 5.0081666 minutes.
```

So your timing is correct.  Since there is no conditional logicin your while loop, other than terminating on an exception, the calls in the while loop will always execute.

Comment: Apologies, if my question was not clear. But I never had any confusion with 'DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME' functions. I knew the conversion, it was just that I was not sure if the 'WHILE' loop was waiting for each Procedure to execute or not.

Comment: Your answer seems to be logical that the procedure 'P_TEMP_PURGE' might be terminating on an exception. Looks like I have to test it more. Thank-you.